# Allow technologies to be printed in the education section of Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

For reference, please visit [my Careers page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/SJBijzitter) and scroll down to the *education* section.

As you can see, I have listed my years through all kind of educational systems. For each year, I have also listed the technologies I learned in that year and I plan to include a small story for each year as I continue to work on my profile in my spare time.

Now please visit my Careers page and [pretend to be a printer](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/168435/print-preview/48625666). The technologies are not being printed, while the technologies in other sections such as *experience* and *projects* are in fact being printed.

I believe this should be changed: technologies should be printed if they are provided! If this raises resistance, we could always make it an option in our profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that was an oversight. I've just fixed it up and pushed to prod so you can see the tags in print preview.

Thanks for the report :)!

Comment: Awesome! Didn't expect it to be this quick)))